# Integrating Tkinter into PYQT -OR- Painting in PYQT

Tags: animation, pyqt, tkinter, paint

Quick question:

I code in PYQT, I had no interest in Tkinter until I found out about it's canvas. I'm making a 2D animation application and I require the canvas, but I also want to do it in PYQT.

I'd love to grab the canvas from tkinter and parent it into my pyqt widget.

Any information would be great, or a link to a tutorial to make the canvas in pyqt because I haven't found any myself after a great deal of searching. I semi-made one in pygame but couldn't parent it into PYQT either.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter and Qt are totally different frameworks, you can't integrate a Tkinter widget into a Qt window. However, Qt has solutions for drawing things.

If you're new on PyQt, I highly recommand [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/). There's a chapter about basic painting. After that, you can just start reading [this documentation](https://doc.qt.io/). This is the documentation for the C++ Qt, but you can still apply it to PyQt, because Qt classes in python have the same methods and attributes :) You just have to adapt the c++ syntax to python. You can even find tutorials [there](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html).

When you're comfortable enough with PyQt, you can look into painting : I think you can either [paint on a widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) (if you don't have many items to paint) or use the [GraphicsView architecture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) (more complex but more fit for drawing). Both ways are going to be a bit more difficult than the TKinter canvas, because Qt is a big framework and has many options.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is Qt, even on Python, you can subclass QWidget, reimplement paintEvent and draw with QPainter. Any widget is canvas in this sense (but paintEvent is protected.)